# getting error for libgtkglext1 & gksu while sudo apt-get install ubuntu-after-install

Tags: 14.04, apt, libreoffice

I have ubuntu 14.04 with 64 bit

When i do `sudo apt-get -f install`

I am getting this error

```
high-tech@hightech-Vostro-3558tio:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgcrypt11 : Breaks: libgcrypt11:i386 (!= 1.5.4-2ubuntu1.1) but 1.5.3-2ubuntu4.3 is installed
 libgcrypt11:i386 : Breaks: libgcrypt11 (!= 1.5.3-2ubuntu4.3) but 1.5.4-2ubuntu1.1 is installed
 libgcrypt11-dev : Depends: libgcrypt11 (= 1.5.3-2ubuntu4.3) but 1.5.4-2ubuntu1.1 is installed
 libnss3-1d : Depends: libnss3 (= 2:3.21-0ubuntu0.14.04.2) but 2:3.19.2.1-0ubuntu0.14.04.2 is installed
 libnss3-nssdb : Depends: libnss3 (= 2:3.21-0ubuntu0.14.04.2) but 2:3.19.2.1-0ubuntu0.14.04.2 is installed
 upwork : Depends: gksu but it is not installable
          Depends: libgtkglext1 but it is not installable
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

i did below solution to solve this

```
sudo apt-get install --fix-broken
```

but its not working for me still i am getting same error.

please help me to solve this.

Comment: If you're using any PPA remove them using `ppa-purge` and then try installing again

Comment: i have not added ppa-purge